# JMeter Requests are concurrent requests or sequential requests?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am new to JMeter, I want to do load testing on a particular web site.

I have to do load test for the following requests on my web site

-->Visiting login page

-->Login to website

-->visiting to products page

-->Visiting to product details page

for this I made script like this

Test Plan

```
|-->ThreadGroup

     |-->Visiting login page
     |-->Login to website
     |-->visiting to products page  and etc..
```

Now, If I run this test plan with 50 threads then what will be the flow ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 50 threads will each one sequentially execute the transactions under Thread Group.

So it is sequential per Thread but parallel for all threads, meaning at the same time (second or minute depending on your pauses and response times) you can have:

- 1 Threads running Visiting login page
- 10 Threads running Login
- 5 threads running visiting to products page  and etc
- others waiting (if you use timers)

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers. If i want to execute all the request for 1 user completely and then I want to start the another thread . How can I achieve that ??